# SIGABRT in Ray Wenderlich's Mapkit Tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

So I am following along with Ray Wenderlich's Mapkit tutorial found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial). I am stuck on the section where I am supposed to plot the crimes on a map with the `plotCrimePositions` method. With the debugger I have narrowed it down to where I am creating `NSDictionary* root` but can not seem to locate the bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Here is a gist with relevant files.](https://gist.github.com/4366279)

Thanks!

EDIT: here is my console log:

```
2012-12-23 16:31:52.925 MapTutorial[8993:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1850012 0x1645e7e 0x184fdeb 0x117a817 0x34697 0x35153 0x1659705 0x590920 0x7ccb24 0x1659705 0x590920 0x5908b8 0x651671 0x651bcf 0x650d38 0x5c033f 0x5c0552 0x59e3aa 0x58fcf8 0x223bdf9 0x223bad0 0x17c5bf5 0x17c5962 0x17f6bb6 0x17f5f44 0x17f5e1b 0x223a7e3 0x223a668 0x58d65c 0x341cd 0x2945)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Sure you're getting a SIGABRT, but you should also be getting a stack trace and a more helpful error in the console.  What are those?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is coming from the fact that `root` is nil because `responseData` is nil in the `refreshTapped` method.

Comment: Moral: tutorials are not for copy-pasting, especially not old tutorials.

Comment: thanks, i did in fact type it all out and spent a decent amount of time trying to debug it. i had never used an ajax call in objective c before and didnt put it together that the method call should have been in the success block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
- (IBAction)refreshTapped:(id)sender{
    //...
    [request startAsynchronous]; //Start the request
    [self plotCrimePositions:request.responseData]; //Assume there's data, 
    //despite the request not even have been given a chance to start
}
```

Because you assumed that your `request` would execute synchronously, then get to that `plotCrimePositions:` when it was finished, you assumed the data the request got was non-nil (obviously not the case), which caused MapKit to flip out.  If you moved `[self plotCrimePositions:request.responseData];` into the scope of the completion handler you specified, it should work like a charm.  Asynchronous requests are asynchronous: meaning they return immediately, which is why completion blocks are such a godsend.